# 'TypeError: str object cannot be interpreted as an integer' What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, typeerror

I keep receiving an error message that str object cannot be interpreted as an integer. I am trying to open a file for reading and then get a value from that file using a variable. I am working with Class in this problem, but this is part of my code.

I need to extract a value from the file that reads in the title of a book.

```
data_file = open('book.txt', 'r')
    title = data_file.readline('r')
```

The expected results should give me the title a book which comes from the file 'book.txt'

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `'r'` to `readline` function, which either takes no argument, or an integer as its argument (for the maximum number of characters to read). Rewrite it like this :

```
data_file = open('book.txt', 'r')
title = data_file.readline()
```

Take a look at [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readline.htm) for more description.

Comment: To add to this, a safer way to read files is to use the `with open('filepath', 'r') as data_file:`